Huygens’ diagram showing a rotating ball flying off along the involute
I’m studying historical derivations of the centrifugal/centripedal acceleration. This thesis has a historical summary.
My question is about Huygens’ figure in his De vi centrifuga.
The figures are not numbered but in the fourth figure the rotating ball when it flies off at B continues on a straight line BH.

Huygens writes:

Let BG be a wheel that rotates parallel to the horizon about center A.
A small ball attached to the circumference, when it arrives at point
B, has a tendency to proceed along the straight line BH, which is
tangent to the wheel at B.

But on the next figure,

Huygens appears to say that the ball B will fly off along the involute curve BRS with origin tangent to the radius of the circle:

Now, however, because they lie off the aforesaid lines slightly toward
B, it happens then that the ball tends to recede from the man not
along the straight line coming from center A, but along some curve
that is tangent to the straight line at the point where the man is
standing. That is, if plane PQ is tangent to the wheel at B and is
attached to it and turns along with it, ball B, if it is separated
from the said wheel or plane, will describe with respect to the same
plane and the point B, both of which also continue to move, the curve
BRS, which is tangent at B to the radius AB moved at the same time and
produced.

So in this case, Huygens is saying that a rotating ball flying of at B will describe the curve BRS, “which is tangent at B to the radius AB moved at the same time and produced.”
Why would the ball fly off on BRS, instead of tangent to the circle? Am I misreading what Huygens is saying?
Edit:
I just found this article. Fig. 3 on page 293 explains the curve  BRS as “path of zero-force body as seen from a rotating frame.”

Does this mean that the ball flies of along the tangent to circle at B but we would see the curve BRS if we continue to rotate at point B?
Edit


Yes, it does mean that. If we continue to rotate then the tangent along which the ball moves will look to us as if attached to a point rotating the other way. As the ball moves along the tangent uniformly, its position will appear as if attached to the end of a taut string unwrapping from  the wheel, which is the geometric definition of the involute.

@Conifold  "rotating the other way..." I cannot visualize this motion. I added a new diagram. Since the rotation is counterclockwise the ball flying off along the tangent will be at point A. This looks on the opposite side of what is drawn in Huygens' diagram.

Think about it in the rest frame first. The man is moving along the circle and the ball along the tangent at the fly-off point. Their speeds are the same, so at any time the man covers the same distance along the circumference as the ball along the tangent. This is as if the ball is attached to the end of a taut string wrapped around the wheel and unwrapping backwards from the man's point of view.

Trying to understood the question fully. What are the equations of motion that produce straight line and involute motions? To guess the dynamics ( $ \psi$ instantaneous radius to trajectory angle), if we consider all free unattached straight shoots without centrifugal force then the relative trajectory is $r \sin \psi$ is constant (all tangents) and if centripetal force is considered then we should have an orthogonal constrained trajectory $r \cos \psi$  of all involute trajectories?

@Conifold I understand your explanations and I drew several figures but I could never make the string "unwrap backwards." I must be having a mental block. So I give up for now. But can you recommend a book where the history of the circular motion is treated in more detail than the thesis I linked to in my question? Thanks
